# Is this structure too large?

Tags: c, struct

The structure I am speaking of is the very last one.  I get segmentation faults when I try to use it, and when I use sizeof to get its size 218369176 is returned.

```
typedef struct
{
unsigned long       a1; /* Last structure in group. */
unsigned long       a2; /* Next structure in group. */
char            rc; /* Representing character. */
short           st; /* Type of structure (purpose). */
short           pl; /* Privilege level required to alter. */
short           vt; /* Type of value (short, char, int, long, float, double, void*). */
union
{
    short       s;
    char        c;
    int     i;
    long        l;
    float       f;
    double      d;
    void*       p;
}           un; /* Union containing values to be stored. */
} index_struct;             /* Structure composing a table tree. */

typedef struct
{
unsigned long       sr;                             /* Script return value. */
unsigned long       ir;                             /* Interpreter return value. */
unsigned long       lc;                             /* Execution counter (text division interpreter stopped at). */
short           ai;                             /* Action identifier (current status of interpretation). */
short           pr;                             /* Script privilege information. */
char            st[65536 /* Change SCRIPT_TEXT_SIZE with this. */];     /* Segment containing script text. */
index_struct        lt[65536 /* Change LOCAL_TREE_SIZE with this. */];      /* Segment containing local tree. */
} script_struct;                                        /* Structure containing script state information and variables. */

typedef struct
{
unsigned long       us;                         /* Number of unjoined scripts. */
unsigned long       sn;                         /* Number of running scripts. */
short           es;                         /* Environment status. */
script_struct       sl[100 /* Change MAX_NUMBER_SCRIPTS with this. */]; /* Segment containing script list. */
index_struct        gt[65536 /* Change GLOBAL_TREE_SIZE with this. */]; /* Segment containing global tree. */
} environment_struct;
```

EDIT:  by popular request, here is the entire source code file.

```
/*
 * BY:  Charles Edwin Swain the 3rd.
 * LANGUAGES:  C and (if I ever comment out certain sections of code) x86 Assembly.
 */

#include <stdio.h>

/*
#include <stdint.h>

const uint8_t CPUID_UNSPECIFIED = 0;
const uint8_t CPUID_SUPPORTED = 1;
const uint8_t CPUID_UNSUPPORTED = 2;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t    maximum_standard_level;
    uint32_t    raw_vendorid[4];
    uint32_t    raw_processortypeORfamilyORmodelORstepping;
    uint32_t    num_extendedfamily;
    uint32_t    num_extendedmodel;
    uint32_t    num_type;
    uint32_t    num_family;
    uint32_t    
    uint32_t    raw_brandidORCLUFLUSHORCPUcountORAPICID;
    uint32_t    raw_featureflags_A;
    uint32_t    raw_featureflags_B;
    uint8_t features[64];
} CPUID_struct;
*/

/* These constants are associated with certain hard coded limits, and all must be the same to ensure proper functionality. */
const unsigned long SCRIPT_TEXT_SIZE    = 65536;    /* Size of segment containing script text. */
const unsigned long GLOBAL_TREE_SIZE    = 65536;    /* Size of segment composing global tree. */
const unsigned long LOCAL_TREE_SIZE = 65536;    /* Size of segments composing local trees. */
const unsigned long MAX_NUMBER_SCRIPTS  = 100;      /* Maximum number of running scripts in an environment. */

typedef struct
{
    unsigned long       a1; /* Last structure in group. */
    unsigned long       a2; /* Next structure in group. */
    char            rc; /* Representing character. */
    short           st; /* Type of structure (purpose). */
    short           pl; /* Privilege level required to alter. */
    short           vt; /* Type of value (short, char, int, long, float, double, void*). */
    union
    {
        short       s;
        char        c;
        int     i;
        long        l;
        float       f;
        double      d;
        void*       p;
    }           un; /* Union containing values to be stored. */
} index_struct;             /* Structure composing a table tree. */

typedef struct
{
    unsigned long       sr;                             /* Script return value. */
    unsigned long       ir;                             /* Interpreter return value. */
    unsigned long       lc;                             /* Execution counter (text division interpreter stopped at). */
    short           ai;                             /* Action identifier (current status of interpretation). */
    short           pr;                             /* Script privilege information. */
    char            st[65536 /* Change SCRIPT_TEXT_SIZE with this. */];     /* Segment containing script text. */
    index_struct        lt[65536 /* Change LOCAL_TREE_SIZE with this. */];      /* Segment containing local tree. */
} script_struct;                                        /* Structure containing script state information and variables. */

typedef struct
{
    unsigned long       us;                         /* Number of unjoined scripts. */
    unsigned long       sn;                         /* Number of running scripts. */
    short           es;                         /* Environment status. */
    script_struct       sl[100 /* Change MAX_NUMBER_SCRIPTS with this. */]; /* Segment containing script list. */
    index_struct        gt[65536 /* Change GLOBAL_TREE_SIZE with this. */]; /* Segment containing global tree. */
} environment_struct;                                   /* Structure containing environment state information and global tree. */

/*
 * Function definition and calling conventions follow:
 *
 *  - All non-interpreter functions should be called through a wrapper function.
 *  - This wrapper function's address is specified through the p field of an index_struct in the global tree.
 *  - The return items of the function are specified through the global tree, under 'f_retu'.
 *  - The arguments to the function are specified through the global tree, under 'f_argv'.
 *  - The number of arguments to the function are specified through the global tree, under 'f_argc'.
 *  - Before calling the wrapper function, these fields and the environment status are appropriately set.
 *  - The wrapper function takes a pointer to the segment containing the global tree as an argument (outside the interpreter).
 *  - The wrapper function sorts through the arguments and calls the appropriate function it is wrapping.
 *  - Once this function returns, it sets any actual interpreter buffers accordingly.
 *  - What is meant by the above is that the wrapper function will use temporary buffers in the call to the function, then transfer data over according to global tree arguments.
 *  - Once the wrapper function returns, the calling (interpreter) code should copy all data from the return to an appropriate location and wipe all involved tables (for security).
 *  - This entire state is uninterruptable by interruption code from the moment the interpreter begins the call to after the interpreter finishes wiping data.
 *  - The above does not include signals, and only describes with regard to the interpreter auto returning after interpreting some input.
 *
 */

/* Creates a fresh interpreter environment. */
int ecreate(environment_struct* environment)
{
    if (environment == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (environment->es != 0)
        {
            return -2;
        }
        else
        {
            environment->us = 0;
            environment->sn = 0;
            environment->es = 1;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

/* Cleans up and shuts down an interpreter environment. */
int edestroy(environment_struct* environment)
{
    if (environment == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (environment->es == 0)
        {
            return -2;
        }
        else
        {
            environment_struct environment_B;
            *environment = environment_B;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

/* Main function. */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
/* This is where the sizeof is.  Works fine when code behind next comment is not commented in.*/
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(environment_struct));
/* Next comment. */
    environment_struct environment;
    int r_ecreate, r_edestroy;
    r_ecreate   = ecreate(&environment);
    r_edestroy  = edestroy(&environment);
    printf("%d, %d\n", r_ecreate, r_edestroy);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us more code, especially the line with the `sizeof`.

Comment: It  is if you are trying to put it on the stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`index_struct` will have a size of 24 bytes on your average 32-bit system (or 32 bytes on your average 64-bit system).

`script_struct` will have a size of 1,638,416 bytes (1.6 MB) on your average 32-bit system (or 2,162,720 bytes (2.16 MB) on your average 64-bit system).

`environment_struct` will have a size of 165,414,476 (165.4 MB) on your average 32-bit system (or 218,369,176 bytes (218.3 MB) on your average 64-bit system (which is the size you're seeing)).

That is an *insanely* large size for a `struct`, and very well might crash your system (particularly if you use it on the stack). If you allocate several `environment_struct`s (on the heap), you could very well run out of memory.

So yeah, they're too large. Waaay too large.

Edit: Yup, you're declaring a `environment_struct` on the stack. A struct that big is insane for the stack.

Comment: Due to alignment, on a 64-bit machine, `index_struct` is more likely to be 32 bytes. This accounts pretty accurately for his numbers. And the quick solution is to make it a global instead.

Comment: Concur with @Potatoswatter. That's exactly what it is on my 64bit Mac.

Comment: Yeah, I was giving *very* conservative numbers (just to show that even when being very conservative, it's still problematic). I'll make a mention of that.

Comment: I predict this answer will seem quaint in a few years.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I've edited it to include actual sizes on typical 32 and 64-bit systems.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small addendum to Cornstalks' answer. On a 64-bit Intel system, the sizes would be, according to my calculations:

```
sizeof(index_struct) = 32
sizeof(script_struct) = 2162716
sizeof(environment_struct) = 218368770
```

Therefore, the result you get from `sizeof` are correct.

In your code, you are putting `environment_struct` on the stack. The stack space is usually fixed and quite limited - on my system it's just 8 MiB. If you really want to use such a gigantic structure, you should allocate the memory for it with `malloc()`. A better approach, which would also remove the rather arbitrary limit of 65536 scripts, would be to store a linked list or array of scripts allocated with `malloc()`, instead of reserving a fixed amount of space.